# UDP Hole Punching

Tags: visual-c++

Can Anyone give me brief detail about the resources used in UDP HolePunching as well as operation of Udp hole punching ? It can be of Any platform I only wan tto know logic.

Thanks in Advance..
Manish Karma

Comment: Do you mean [UPNP NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp#NAT_traversal)?

Comment: I mean User Datagram Protocol Hole Punching through NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Found the Following Link** 
 [Link] http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

Manish Karma

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're making "holes" and then throwing "darts" into the holes. The "holes" are NAT table entries and the "darts are UDP packets".

Please read the section entitled "Background Information":

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1IimJ20gG0SY2NvaE4wRVVMbG8/view?usp=sharing